# C++ program not able to find math.h when compiling with CMake and including OpenCV libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to compile an opencv project using cmake on Mac. When I try to compile, I am presented with this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:301:10: fatal error: 'math.h' file not found
```

Telling me math.h is not found. The library definitely exists because when I compile without cmake, it works fine.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project( Optimotive )
find_package( OpenCV )

file(GLOB_RECURSE Optimotive_SOURCES "../Optimotive/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE Optimotive_HEADERS "../Optimotive/*.h")

set(Optimotive_INCLUDE_DIRS "")
foreach(_headerFile ${Optimotive_HEADERS})
        get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
        list(APPEND Optimotive_INCLUDE_DIRS ${_dir})
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES Optimotive_INCLUDE_DIRS)

include_directories(${Optimotive_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(Optimotive ${Optimotive_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(Optimotive ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: 1) Are you required to use an ancient CMake? 2.8 is very old. 2) When using newer CMake that whole `include_directories` should be replaced by a simple `target_include_directories(Optimotive PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../Optimotive)` making the `foreach` obsolete. 4) Are you sure CMake detected the correct compiler?

Comment: Yea, I might benefit from using an updated version of CMake, but it should still work with old. Also, I'm not sure how know if it is detecting the right compiler.

Comment: If you go in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/`, what do you get if you do `find . -iname math.h`? BTW, indeed that foreach seems overkill. Maybe this has nothing to do with Opencv, try to write a small program that includes math.h

Comment: Ok, I did the `find` thing and it printed a bunch of directories. I did try it in a simple program to include math.h and it seemed to work fine. Not sure what the issue here could be.

Comment: You may need to update your Xcode tools if you have upgraded OSX to keep them in step. Open `AppStore` and do any updates needed and then update your Xcode with `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Ayyy, that worked. Thank you friend.